# Is Doughnut Pie chart possible in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, cross-platform, pie-chart

Is it possible to create a doughnut pie chart as shown below in xamarin forms(cross platform) using oxyplot or any other library.If yes can you help me with the link or example. I did find solution to implement pie chart but couldn't find solution to implement doughnut pie chart.

[image]

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Yes it is. Good luck :)

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: And yes, my comment was not very nice. But I tried to make a small point and not be rude here. At Stack Overflow we try to stimulate questions that show some effort in terms of what have you tried, what did you find? What are you looking for exactly? Your question as formulated right now will yield bad responses as per "crap in, crap out". Also, we do this voluntarily. I am happy to help in any way I can, but I will not do your work for you. Please update your question to be a bit more informative.

Comment: @Gerald Versluis Edited my question :) Thank you

Comment: I did not ask anybody to do my work, I only asked for help in terms of links or any information which can help me as I am beginner at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my answer by referring these below links:

[OxyPlot Piechart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37111422/how-can-i-create-doughnut-chart-using-oxyplot-in-xamarin-android/37702088) and [How can i create doughnut chart using oxyplot in xamarin.android?](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/71825/oxyplot-pie-chart-not-appearing-in-xamarin-forms-portable-application)

```
public class SalesVM
{
    private PlotModel modelP1;
    public SalesVM()
    {
        modelP1 = new PlotModel { Title = "Pie Sample1" };

        dynamic seriesP1 = new PieSeries { StrokeThickness = 2.0, InsideLabelPosition = 0.8, AngleSpan = 360, StartAngle = 0, InnerDiameter = 0.8};

        seriesP1.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Africa", 1030) { IsExploded = false, Fill = OxyColors.PaleVioletRed });
        seriesP1.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Americas", 929) { IsExploded = true });
        seriesP1.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Asia", 4157) { IsExploded = true });
        seriesP1.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Europe", 739) { IsExploded = true });
        seriesP1.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Oceania", 35) { IsExploded = true });

        modelP1.Series.Add(seriesP1);

    }

    public PlotModel Model1
    {
        get { return modelP1; }
        set { modelP1 = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: How you have use this in forms?